# Groovy - if statement in list

Tags: if-statement, groovy

how can I write next statement like in a python code:

```
if x in [a, b ,c]:
    print("print something..")
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy has an in operator too, see the  [language documentation:](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html)

> 8.5. Membership operator
>
> The membership operator (in) is equivalent to calling the isCase method. In the context of a List, it is equivalent to calling contains, like in the following example:
>
> ```
> def list = ['Grace','Rob','Emmy']
> assert ('Emmy' in list)
> ```
>
> equivalent to calling list.contains('Emmy') or list.isCase('Emmy')